# Loading a dll at run-time - Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll

I use a dll that has above 300 functions and I need at least 50 of them.
I need to load the functions during run time using LoadLibrary , GetProcAddress etc.
My problem is that my code is becoming too huge, around 500 lines. 
Is there a more refined method ?

Comment: I deal with this using a class that wraps a DLL. It handles the binding using calls to GetProcAddress. I supply a list of function pointer variables and names. It does the rest, all the binding and error checking. That's the kind of thing you need to do. Still have to declare the function pointer variables but there's no way to avoid that.

Comment: I'm doing what @DavidHeffernan described. My class is part of dzLib, which is MPL. If you want to use it, you can find it on sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/p/dzlib/code/HEAD/tree/dzlib/trunk/src/u_dzDllLoader.pas

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which version of Delphi you are using, you might find it easier to use Delphi's **Delay Load** feature by adding the [`delayed`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Libraries_and_Packages#Delayed_Loading) keyword to the DLL function declarations and let Delphi handle the `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` calls for you.